# (Need help)- Can I wire a ceiling fan/light fixture from an existing 3-way switched outlet?

Tags: electrical, wiring, switch, light

Link to Imgur for pictures with reference drawings: https://i.stack.imgur.com/APfnD.jpg

As title says, I'm trying to wire a new ceiling fan/light fixure. I currently have a 3 way switch that controls one switched outlet. I am pretty confident that my source power is running to the switch closest to the outlet.

My question is, is it possible to just run 12/2 wires from the outlet that is switched(half hot) directly to my new fan for power and a switch? I would rather not mess with rewiring the switch, and as long as the outlet stays on with my fan/light being on I would be content. I understand basic wiring, but I'm unsure of how to connect my wires from my ceiling box to this switched outlet.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. What do you mean by "a three way switch"? Would you upload a diagram of what you're asking? And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Comment: Can we have photos that look into the backs of the boxes involved?

Comment: I'll get some more pictures posted this morning. I have two light switches which both control the top half of one outlet. I am trying to look at the best way to tie a ceiling fan/light into the circut. Power enters at one of the switches, and I'm hoping to run one set of wires from my new fan and pigtail them into the exisiting switch.